# Openssl init, add cipher and cleanup questions

Tags: android, openssl

I was using openssl in native to encrypt or decrypt my data for android. I am naive in this field. I just made a study and added the implementation.

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

I was referencing this to use and modify a bit as below:

```
/* Initialise the library */
    //Add the ciper algorithm.
    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_256_cbc());
    //use the default config.
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, t, &outlen, s,  size);
    ...
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, t + tlen, &outlen);
    ...

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_cleanup();
```

But there comes the problem, calling EVP_cleanup causing java side https open connection exception. errors like SSL_CTX_new returning NULL. Some discussion mentioned that it should not be called EVP_cleanup, it will globally clean up the table algorithms. So i remove the EVP_cleanup. the crash solved.

But when i test for memory usage native, calling 100, 200...times of the above function. The native heap increases each time.

I removed these 2 lines. It still can successfully encrypt, decrypt with EVP_ases_256_cbc.

```
/* Initialise the library */
//Add the ciper algorithm.
//EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_256_cbc()); 
//use the default config.
//OPENSSL_config(NULL);
```

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization#OPENSSL_config

1. How the ssl in initiated and all the algorithms are loaded?

I also tested with replacing EVP_cleanup() with OPENSSL_no_config();

```
/* Initialise the library */
    //Add the ciper algorithm.
    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_256_cbc());
    //use the default config.
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, t, &outlen, s,  size);
    ...
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, t + tlen, &outlen);
    ...

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    //unload the config. 
    OPENSSL_no_config();
```

This above implementation, seems not causing native heap increasing.

My questions are as below:

> 1. Without calling any initialization, like
>
>    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms or SSL_load_error_strings or
>      EVP_add_cipher;
>
>    what is the default ssl add algorithms or cipher?
> 2. when to use OPENSSL_config? is it necessary to use in my case?
> 3. My last solution of replacing EVP_cleanup with OPENSSL_no_config() is the acceptable solution for native heap increasing leak?

Comment: Openssl_config seems to use for ca, X509. It seems that it is not necessary in my case.